# async as a method result manager?

Tags: c#, async-await

[*From here*](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) :

> The `“async”` keyword enables the “await” keyword in that method **and**
>   *changes how method results are handled*. That’s all the async keyword
>   does!

The second part got me interesting , but I didn't find explanation to this in the article.

Doing a little test ( notice  - no awaited tasks are here) :

```
  static void X()
    {
        try
        {
            Y();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    static async void Y() //<---- notice here
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        X();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This will *terminate* the program :

[image]

While *removing*  `async` from this :

```
 static async void Y()  
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Will yield :

[image]

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx) says nothing about it :

> If the method that the async keyword modifies doesn't contain an await
>   expression or statement, the method executes synchronously. A compiler
>   warning alerts you to any async methods that don't contain await,
>   because that situation might indicate an error

**Question**

If so , what *else* does the word `async` does that my code yields different results ?

Comment: I'm not sure why it was down voted either. Good question in my opinion

Comment: Stephen Cleary's newer article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx goes into more details on exceptions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`async` methods catch all exceptions, don't throw them up the stack to the caller of the method, and instead include them in the `Task` returned from the method, marking it as a faulted `Task`.  If the method is `async void`, the error is thrown at an application level, as you have seen, since there is no way to observe the exception through a `Task`.

Comment: This showed up in the low quality queue. I could not understand why, but it turned out to be an audit.

Comment: So [this](https://i.imgur.com/0ytq8TW.jpg) is not accurate.(from [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)). With a combination of void , it throws exception in the application level. it is not only allows the await keyword

Comment: @RoyiNamir No, that's not wrong.  That quote specifically mentions that it changes how the results of the method are handled, in this case, how exceptions are propogated.

Comment: @Servy Yes. I didn't read the second part. sorry and thank you :-)